# Logitech controller not passing into Centos virtual machine as joystick

Tags: centos, usb, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a Logitech Dual Action Controller that I am trying to use in a Centos virtual machine (using VirtualBox). The controller is in "D" mode (according to the switch on the back of the controller) and is passing through to the vm as  `Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c216 Logitech, Inc. Dual Action Gamepad`.

It shows up in `/dev/input` as `event7`. It should come up as `js0` indicating that it is a joystick input.

I have tried:

- Updating my kernel - no change
- Installing joy-dev - no change
- Running evtest to test the input of the controller - Evtest did not have any output no matter what button I pressed on the controller.
- Using the controller in "X" mode (switch on the back of the controller) - Didn't create a new event or joystick in /dev/input.

Does anybody have any suggestions about how to correctly pass this controller through to my vm as a joystick?? I am out of ideas.

Thanks

Per the comment:

The output of dmesg when I grep for Logitech is:

[ 8308.864059] usb 2-1: Product: Logitech Dual Action

[ 8308.864061] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Logitech

[ 8318.897422] input: Logitech Logitech Dual Action as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/input/input7

[ 8318.897859] hid-generic 0003:046D:C216.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 
Joystick [Logitech Logitech Dual Action] on usb-0000:00:06.0-1/input0

Only **one** new event is created when I plug the controller in. While running Evtest for event7, nothing happens when I push buttons or move the joystick on the controller.

Comment: Please add output of `dmesg` when you plug it in. Apparently the kernel recognizes it as an HID device or something instead of a joystick, so I suspect it loads the wrong driver (though google says this device uses an HID interface). Do you see events when you move the stick? Are there possibly several /dev/input devices associated with the joystick?

Comment: Have you tried installing [VirtualBox Guest Additions](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Virtualization/VirtualBox/CentOSguest) in the Guest OS?

Comment: Take a look to udev rules. May be an existing rule mapping the joystick  to the wrong device or you can add your own rule.